# Flickity doesn't always load (Shopify)

Tags: javascript, shopify, flickity

I am using flickity to make carousels in my Shopify store. An odd thing happens when it sometimes does not load. It happens sometimes, not always. I could not find anything in the console to help understand why this is happening. Refreshing the page usually gives the correct result

Things I've already tried:

1. Using only 1 of the 2 Flickity components, still doesn't work
2. Hosting the css and js files on Shopify's servers vs. unpkg.com (where it is normally hosted)

Website: https://4s6snnbh0sbvzjnb-5771952162.shopifypreview.com

What sometimes happens:
[image]
[image]

Intended Result (happens after you refresh):
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, but very rarely happen maybe 1/ 100.

Comment: Mine is probably 1/2

Comment: I think there is a trick that you applied it  tested and works well for me.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/o-nkar/1a7db6a870bd4aafa838245aada6b3f3

Comment: I've implemented this and will report back

Comment: This works. Feel free to submit answer and I will accept. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to know it works, Sure I will add the same to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some situations where the slider is not working properly due to some JS conflicts or content loading issues like slow-loading images.
there is a small trick that triggers the Flickity slider to work.

```
// trigger a resize event once the window is loaded, it refresh the Flickity slider on resize
window.onload = function(){
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}
```

When the window is resized slider recalculate it with and slide to show etc, so if there is an issue that causes random failure of the slider.

Then we generate a javascript code `resize` event, and the slider works perfectly.